# What if I am ok with 'Cannot read property '****' of undefined'?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some code which looks like following:

```
$scope.query.toLowerCase() != 1
```

If query is not defined - there is an error in the console. Actually the code still produces the result that I want, but what is the right approach of dealing with error? Of course I can check the the variable in advance - but that will lead to more code, not sure of the benefits of hiding errors by having to read more code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting an undefined object property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property)

Comment: @Hacketo Does not seem like a duplicate to me.

Comment: You should check it, and throw your own error and then deal with the error in your program, especially if query being defined is a direct consequence of a user providing the proper input.  If this should never happen with any type of user input, then let it fail as is.

Comment: Come on, I do know how to check if variable is undefined. The question is - what is the shortes way to write the code. Checking will make the code longer.

Comment: Well, you should ALWAYS add defensive code and test variable definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Of course I can check the the variable in advance - but that will lead to more code

Writing more code doesn't make your code bad, unless you are in a code golf competition. If you don't handle your errors and edge cases, then your program will not be reliable. If a line of code throws an error, your code might even terminate prematurely.

An alternative way to deal with possible undefined properties is to define a default value instead of checking if it is `undefined`.

```
($scope.query || "").toLowerCase() != 1       // this is enough to fix your expression
```

or more formally

```
($scope.query === undefined ? "" : $scope.query).toLowerCase() != 1
```

This obviously depends on what your purpose is.

Another example:

```
function add(a, b){
    return a + (b || 0);  // if b is falsy, assume b is 0
}

add(1, 2);   // 3
add(1);      // 1
```

[Shortcircuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) is very useful in some cases, but make sure you know exactly how it works because misusing it will create unexpected behaviors.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. Of course I could solve the error displaying, but did not want to go with a quick solution and your answer helps a lot to improve my code readabilty.

Comment: "define a default value instead of checking if it is undefined".  your example check `$scope.query` value to use a default value ..

Comment: @Hacketo To clarify what I meant, is instead of using an `if` and introduce a whole new block of code, short circuiting is a faster shortcut to get around it.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 You can use inline `if`: `$scope.query && $scope.query.toLowerCase()` this doesn't add any block of code, thought it may harm readability

Answer (score 1):

Its bad practice to do ...

```
try {
    $scope.query.toLowerCase() != 1
} catch(e) {
    // do nothing
}
```

since this obscures errors and if an unexpected error happens you wont know about it which makes debugging a nightmare.

The approved practice is to write a few extra lines of defensive code to protect against the scenario that would lead to an error.
Yes its more verbose but its better than having a codebase which is a nightmare to debug.

Answer (score 0):

in general: I'm outsorcing this task into a tiny helper:

```
function string(v){ return v==null? "": String(v) }
```

and I can be sure, that the output is always a String (Type-safety).

```
string($scope.query).toLowerCase() != 1
```

In this special case? you are checking against a number, you don't need the `toLowerCase()`

```
+$scope.query !== 1
```

would be even better in this case; an no need to deal with null or undefined.